# Don't generate the *Count method in java protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

According to protobuf documentation

```
Repeated fields have some extra methods – a Count method
```

so something like this:

```
// repeated .tutorial.Person.PhoneNumber phone = 4;
public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneList();
public int getPhoneCount();
public PhoneNumber getPhone(int index);
```

Is it possible to suppress the generation of `getPhoneCount`? I don't want it in the resulting java class. Is it possible to not generate it?

EDIT: To make clear what my problem is, we have .proto file with something like this

```
message Bar {
    ...
    optional int32 entries_count = 123
    ...
    repeated Foo entries = 456
    ...
}
```

Because of that, both `entries_count` and `entries` tries to generate function `getEntriesCount()`, which is obviously not possible. So it's generated instead as `getEntriesCount123()` and `getEntriesCount456()`, which is not exactly user friendly. So I would like to suppress generation of one of them, since they are supposed to return same value anyway.

Sadly I'm not really sure how feasible is changing the format, too many things around may depend on it :/

Comment: I strongly doubt that there is a way to switch that off (short of hacking the proto compiler) because it is a useful method to have - the number of times people don't want it will be dwarfed by the number of times you do.

Comment: well I can hope, maybe someone knows some way :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way of doing this.

If you look at the generator code ([primitive fields](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_primitive_field.cc), [message fields](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_field.cc), [enum fields](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum_field.cc) etc) you can see that the `...Count()` methods (both interface and implementation) are written unconditionally.

Options:

1. Live with the existing generation code
2. Use your own fork of `protoc`
3. Create a pull request for the main project

I'd strongly recommend option 1. With option 2 you'll be forever having to do work to keep it up to date, and I'd be quite surprised if you managed to get option 3 accepted into the codebase... the bar for adding an extra option is pretty high.

Basically, you should remove your `entries_count` field. It's an obvious place where data can get out of sync - and the *real* value is always available to clients anyway, in all platforms I'm aware of. If you want it to mean something other than just "the number of values in `entries`" (e.g. some estimated total count, where you've only got some sample) then you should rename it to be more specific, at which point your existing problem will go away at the same time.

Comment: @Paladin: Sorry, that comment *really* wasn't clear. I suggest you try to express that in a clearer fashion within the text of your question. But please understand that it sounds like your `.proto` is basically structured in a way which will stop anyone using the default Java codegen from using it... I suggest you rethink the feasibility of changing the message.

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully what I need is clearer now. But yep, I know "my" .proto sucks.. will probably look into changing it, wonder how many thinks will break :D

Comment: @Paladin: Right, will edit my answer with that extra information.

Comment: you are right, I really should change the .proto file, the bit about "out of sync" is a good point, that could potentially get pretty messy. thanks